# why do i get variable -- is being used without being initialized error?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, fwrite, initialization

I want to use this program to write a hash table to a file
but i get

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'fpinfo' to 'const void *'

error at compile time

if i change `struct fpinfo e;` with `struct fpinfo *e` i get the run time error:

> The variable 'e' is being used without being initialized.

I tried to initialize e by declaring it as `struct fpinfo *e=NULL;`. This either doesn't work.

Please give me your help as usual.

```
WriteHTtoFile(struct fpinfo t[][B_ENTRIES],int this_tanker,tanker_record tr[][BUCKETS])
{
    //struct fpinfo *e;
    struct fpinfo e;
    int i=0, mask;
    char filename[sizeof ("file0000.txt")];
    sprintf(filename, "filee%d.txt", this_tanker);
    curr_tanker++;
    //fp = fopen(filename,"w");
    FILE *htfile=fopen(filename,"w+b");
     system("cls");
if (htfile != NULL)  
        { 
         for (int j = 0; j < BUCKETS; ++j) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < tr[this_tanker][j].bkt.num_of_entries; ++k)
            {
            printf("%d\t%d\t%s\n",t[j][k].chunk_offset,t[j][k].chunk_length,t[j][k].fing_print);
            (e).chunk_offset=t[j][k].chunk_offset;
            (e).chunk_length=t[j][k].chunk_length;
            strcpy((char*)((e).fing_print),(char*)t[j][k].fing_print);
            fwrite(e,sizeof(fpinfo),1,htfile);
            }
        } 
            fclose(htfile); 
         } 
        else 
        { 
            std::cout<<"File could not be opend for writing";
            printf("Error %d\t\n%s", errno,strerror(errno));
        }

    fclose(htfile);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is C++, not C. Fixed tags.

Comment: What format is the file supposed to be in? It looks like you're just missing the code to convert `e` into whatever format the file is supposed to be in. You can't just write contents of memory into a file and expect it to make sense later unless you've serialized those contents in a known format.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it is a binary file and i have written and read it successfully thanks to you guys all

Comment: A binary file in *what* format? You have to convert into the format the file is supposed to be in. (You have converted your code from code that seems to not work to code that seems to work. But it's still *very* broken because it does not implement a sensible file format -- unless code you haven't shown us is extremely unusual. Your file is an array of bytes, it must be defined at the byte level.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: i don't have advanced knowledge on c or c++. I am just learning it by doing something tangible. Can you please give me more of what you are saying? I mean, how do i do the byte level definition for the file format? And it seems my code is not well organized and planned (i also believe so). so would you give more concrete explanations which can be understood by an inexperienced programmer(student) like me?

Comment: @John: You decide what you want to store in the file. Then you decide how, in bytes, you store that data. For example, if you need to store a number from 0-1,000, you could store it in ASCII decimal using 4 bytes, and "0000" for zero. You could store it using two bytes in hexadecimal with either the most significant byte first or the least significant bytes first. You have to choose the format and lay the data out in the format you chose. For example, skim this overview of some [JPG file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#JFIF_segment_format) bits to get an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `fwrite()` is a `const void*`. This passes a `struct fpinfo`:

```
fwrite(e, sizeof(fpinfo), 1, htfile);
```

Change to:

```
fwrite(&e, sizeof(fpinfo), 1, htfile);
```

I am unsure what the members of `struct fpinfo` are so this may be unsafe (if, for example, it contains any pointer members). Any future reordering of the members in `struct fpinfo` or a change that results in a size increase of `struct fpinfo` (like new members being added) means any attempt to read previously written `struct fpinfo` data will be incorrect.

When the declaration of `e` was changed to a `struct fpinfo* e;` the unitialised error was due to the pointer not being NULL or being assigned to a dynamically allocated `struct fpinfo`.

When changed to `struct fpinfo *e = NULL;` this would cause a segmentation fault when an attempt to access any member of `e` occurred as it is not pointing to a `struct fpinfo`.